# Customise Mailer::DeliverJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer, rescue

I have a system that uses mailer to notify users of any change in their accounts.

I am using `deliver_later` for `async_process`, but need to handle an exception if there are any errors that occur during the delivery process.

The solution I am looking for is to change the `deliver_job` implemented for mailer.

I have read and followed some tutorials like [this one blog tutorial on making custom jobs](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/01/15/rails-5-2-allows-mailers-to-use-custom-active-job-class.html) which suggests:

```
undefined method `delivery_job=' for UserNotifier:Class
  Did you mean?  delivery_method=
```

Can someone tell me how to change the default value `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` ?

Comment: Assuming you are using Rails 5.2 (because it is not available in earlier versions of rails), it would be helpful to see the code you have tried.

Comment: thank you @dbugger, I tried on 2.3 and 5.0, so I think I need to look for another solution.

I am going to try this https://gist.github.com/dnagir/1786236